# Not able to update XML value in Change mode (without admin rights)

Tags: wix

I have written following code in my wix installer for updating the language in an XML file and this works fine in following conditions:

1) fresh install
2) upgrade by using admin rights (I am using msiexec /I "Tools.msi" /l*v D:\InstallLog.txt).

However, when I run/execute the msi without admin rights (This is where "Change" mode is being used....**what am I missing**) the values are not updating always set to the default value :

```
       <Property Id="LANGUAGE" Value="en-US" />
```

[image: Installation (Change mode)]

The code:

```
    <util:XmlFile Id="LanguageConfig"
                  Value="[LANGUAGE]"
                  ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='Language'[\]]"
                  Action="setValue"
                  File="$(var.ConfigFile)"
                  Name="value" Sequence="1" />

    <util:XmlFile Id="MappingLanguageXML"
                  Value="[LANGUAGE]"
                  ElementPath="/MappedUsers/UsersList/UserID/LanguageCode"
                  Action="setValue"
                  File="$(var.UserMappingFile)" Sequence="1"  />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's being changed implies it may not be a privilege issue. I suspect that the scenario is that a different language was entered at install time, *but you did not preserve its value anywhere* so Change just uses the default value. Properties aren't remembered automatically, that's what the WiX "remember property" pattern is for. That's likely to be the solution - preserve the install time value of LANGUAGE.  It's no different from running any program - the fact that the user may have entered something that went into a variable doesn't mean that the variable will have that same value next time you run the program *unless you save it*.

Comment: Many thanks for pointer. It was indeed a privilege issue because the value was updating with admin rights and not updating without it. But based on your pointer on preserving the value, I did find the solution for this issue. I am posting the answer so that other can be benefited from this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [PhilDw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3261150/phildw) pointer I solved the issue by modifying my property

```
<Property Id="LANGUAGE" Value="en-US" />
```

as follows:

```
<Property Id="LANGUAGE" Secure="yes" Value="en-US">
   <RegistrySearch Id="RememberLanguage" Root="HKLM"
            Key="$(var.RegistryLoc)"
            Name="Language" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

By preserving  the value in the registry I was able to modify the value during "Change" operation.